# Matplotlib: Plotting two graphs within a specified x-axis range

Tags: python, matplotlib

Basically I'm in a situation where I want to lock down the starting point of the graph depending on the first graph that's plotted.

e.g. If i do something like this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([7,8,9,10], [1,4,9,16], 'yo')
plt.plot([1,9,11,12], [1,4,9,16], 'ro')
plt.show()
```

I would like a way to restrict the x-axis to start from 7 so (1,1) from the second plot will be removed.

Is there a way to do this? I could keep track of it myself but just curious if there's something built in to handle this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matplotlib offers you two ways:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([7,8,9,10], [1,4,9,16], 'yo')
plt.plot([1,9,11,12], [1,4,9,16], 'ro')
plt.xlim(xmin=7)
plt.show()
```

or the more object-oriented way

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([7,8,9,10], [1,4,9,16], 'yo')
ax.plot([1,9,11,12], [1,4,9,16], 'ro')
ax.set_xlim(xmin=7)
plt.show()
```

If you don't use IPython, I highly recommend it since you can create the axes object and then type `ax.<Tab>` and see all of your options. Autocomplete can be a wonderful thing in this case.

Answer (score 3):

In short: `plt.xlim()`.

In long:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x1, y1 = ([7,8,9,10], [1,4,9,16])
plt.plot(x1, y1, 'yo')
plt.xlim(min(x1), max(x1))
plt.plot([1,9,11,12], [1,4,9,16], 'ro')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can turn auto-scaling off after the first plot  ([doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.autoscale)):

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.autoscale(enable=False)
```

which will lock down all of the scales (you can do x and y separately as well).